# Working with <apex:param> component

Tags: visualforce, controller

[image]

As the above page showing, If i click on the button, the corresponded output should be taken to respected detailed page. But it does not taking into respected output. I tried with following Controller and VF page.

Controller:

```
public class Redirect_Main1 {

   public List<Account> accs { get; set; }
   public ID aid;

    public void access(){
        accs = [select id,name,phone,Industry from account];
        for(Account acc:accs){
            aid = acc.id;
        }
        }
       public String getAccess2(){
         return 'https://ap2.salesforce.com/'+aid;
         }
    }
```

VF Page:

```
    <apex:page Controller="Redirect_Main1" action="{!access}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a.Id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Industry}"/>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Click" action="{!access}"/>
                        <apex:param name="account" assignTo="{!aid}" value="{!access2}"/>
               </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I have tried maximum up to my best, but i could not get respected output. May be i think so, i committed wrong with  component. Please let me know where i did mistake.

Thanking you

KS Kumaar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to over complicate things, this should work

**Apex :**

```
public class Redirect_Main1 {

   public List<Account> accs { get; set; }

    public void access(){
        accs = [select id,name,phone,Industry from account];
    }

 }
```

**VF :** change one line

```
<apex:commandButton value="Click" action="/{!a.id}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code

```
<apex:column >
      <apex:commandButton value="Click" action="{!redirectDetail}" rerender="frm">
            <apex:param name="account" assignTo="{!aid}" value="{!a.Id}"/>
      </apex:commandButton>
 </apex:column>
```

IN Apex

```
public pagereference redirectDetail(){
     return 'https://ap2.salesforce.com/'+aid;
}
```

use `apex:param` inside the `commandButton`

Comment: Hi....Tushar Sharma. Please check my code again. I have updated with one modification at  "return 'https://ap2.salesforce.com/'+aid;"

Comment: I have tried with your suggestions, but corresponded result is not showing....

Comment: @KSKumaar check if you usew rerender and also what is not working for you. And you returning from Access2 but where you want to get this value?

Comment: Hi @Tushar Sharma, I checked with using reRender and also checked with out using reRender. In both conditions it is not working. 
When i click on the particular record button , it does not take me to respected record detailed page.

Comment: @KSKumaar check my updated answer.

Comment: Some what it is working....I am trying to do some modifications.
I will update once i done.
Thank you Thushar Sharma